# Does c++ file ostream or file print function output '\0' to file when output a char array

Tags: c++

I want to write some data to a binary file. I output a char array to a file like this

```cpp
std::ofstream os;
os.open("myfile", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
os<<"A";
os.close();
```

or

```cpp
char a[]="A";
File* file = fopen ("myfile","wb");
fprintf(file,"%s",a);
```

And in the end, does the file includes the '\0'?

In other words, the data of the file is 0x41 or 0x4100 in hexadecimal。

Comment: Try it, and use a hex-dump to see the actual contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And in the end, does the file includes the '\0'?

No. Strings are printed excluding terminating zero byte.

Comment: If you *want* the null terminator written, use (in the case of `std::ofstream`) `os.write()` instead, eg: `os.write("A", 2);` or `os.write(a, strlen(a)+1);`